# Matrix equation $XAXBXC=I$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A,B,C$ be unitary matrices. Does there always exist a unitary matrix $X$ such that $$(XA)(XB)(XC)=I,$$ where $I$ is the identity matrix? The quadratic equation $(XA)(XB)=I$ has the solution $A^*(AB^*)^{1/2}$, and I am hoping that the cubic and higher dimensional versions are always solvable.

Comment: By making the change of variables $X = A^* \tilde X$ one may reduce without loss of generality to the case $A=I$, or equivalently to the equation $BXC = X^{-2}$.

Comment: Yes I have tried that but it does not seem to help much. The only case that I can solve this equivalent equation is when B and C commute.

Comment: In the case where it is ok to compute the square-roots, a numerical computation seems to yield an $X$ that solves the equation mentioned by Terry Tao. In particular, I run the "fixed-point" iteration: $W \gets B\sqrt{W}^*C$ to "convergence" and set $X=\sqrt{W}^*$; this seems to satisfy the equation!

Comment: A question about the solution of the quadratic equation. How do you define the square root ? This is an important issue, because in order that $A^*(AB^*)^{1/2}$ be a solution, it seems that we need to apply twice the identity $f(MN)M=Mf(NM)$, which requires some assumption about $f$ (here the square root) and the spectrum of teh matrices at stake.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Here is an argument showing that the answer is 'yes'.  I'll let you check the details and that this result generalizes to all higher degrees.

Consider the map $f_{ABC}:\mathrm{U}(n)\to\mathrm{U}(n)$ defined by
$$
f_{ABC}(X) = XAXBXC.
$$
Since the image of this map is compact, if this map were not onto, it would have to have topological degree equal to zero.

Next, since $\mathrm{U}(n)$ is connected, the map $f_{ABC}:\mathrm{U}(n)\to\mathrm{U}(n)$ defined by
$$
f_{ABC}(X) = XAXBXC
$$
is homotopic to the map $f_{III}$, and hence has the same degree as $f_{III}$. Thus, it suffices to show that the map $f_{III}$ has nonzero topological degree to show that $f_{ABC}$ is surjective.

I claim that the map $f_{III}$ has topological degree $3^n$.

To prove this, it suffices to compute the local degrees around the pre-images of a regular value.  Let $Y = \mathrm{diag}(e^{i\theta_1},\ldots,e^{i\theta_n})$, where $0<\theta_1<\theta_2<\cdots<\theta_n<\pi$.  Then $Y$ has distinct eigenvalues.  Hence, any solution $X$ to $X^3 = Y$ has distinct eigenvalues and has the same eigendirections as $Y$. Thus, $X$, too, must be diagonal and must be of the form
$$
X = \mathrm{diag}(e^{i\tau_1},\ldots,e^{i\tau_n})
$$
where $3\tau_k \equiv \theta_k\ \mathrm{mod}\ 2\pi$ for $k=1,\ldots, n$.  Thus, there are $3^n$ solutions $X$ to $X^3=Y$.

I claim that $Y$ is a regular value of the map $f_3:\mathrm{U}(n)\to \mathrm{U}(n)$ defined by $f_3(X)=X^3$ and that $f_3$ is orientation preserving at each solution $X$ of $X^3=Y$.  This follows from the following computation:  Consider the pullback under $f_3$ of the canonical left-invariant form $g^{-1}\mathrm{d} g$.
$$
f_3^*(g^{-1}\mathrm{d}g) = g^{-3}\mathrm{d}(g^3) 
= (I + \mathrm{Ad}(g^{-1})+\mathrm{Ad}(g^{-2}))(g^{-1}\mathrm{d}g)
$$
When one computes the determinant of $\bigl(I + \mathrm{Ad}(X^{-1})+\mathrm{Ad}(X^{-2})\bigr):{\frak{u}}(n)\to {\frak{u}}(n)$ for each solution $X$ of $X^3=Y$, one finds that, because $Y$ has distinct eigenvalues, this determinant is a positive number.  Thus, $Y$ is a regular value of $f_3$, and each of the $3^n$ solutions $X$ to $X^3=Y$ contributes a $+1$ to the topological degree in the usual degree formula.

(By a similar argument, the map $f_k:\mathrm{U}(n)\to\mathrm{U}(n)$ defined by $f(X) = X^k$ has topological degree $k^n$, which is nonzero, so it is necessarily surjective. This answers the higher degree cases as well.)

Comment: For concluding that degree is not 0 it suffices to verify that almost all points in the image have odd number of preimages.

Comment: @FedorPetrov:  Yes, that's true, but that argument won't work when you go to treat the even degree cases, and I wanted to indicate how that would be done, since the OP did ask about that.

Comment: This idea appears in paper of Gerstenhaber and Rothaus. The degree of the map was calculated by Hopf in "Ueber den Rang ..."

Comment: @AntonPetrunin:  Thanks for the reference.  I did not know this result before, but I'm not at all surprised that the degree of the $k$-th power map is known for all compact Lie groups.  It would be surprising if it weren't known.

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT2:** Thanks to Robert Bryant for clearing the unitary fog. My argument on existence is wrong, as it tries to run Brouwer on $U(n)$ (how silly!).

But because the Matlab code that I included seems to often construct a solution, I'm leaving that part of the answer here. The rest, I've excised.

---

Following Terry Tao's comment, I aim to solve
$$X^{-2}=BXC.$$

Consider now the map
$$\mathcal{G} : U \mapsto B\sqrt{U}^*C.$$

Alas, it is not easy to ensure that this is a fixed-point map (in fact, the $\sqrt$ operation is not even continuous), otherwise we'd be done. However, numerically it seems to yield a unitary matrix $W$ such that upon setting $X^{-1}=\sqrt{W}$ which satisfies $X^{-2}=BXC$.

The following matlab code almost always manages to also construct such a solution! I haven't looked in to see, what particular square-roots does 'sqrtm' in Matlab return for unitary matrices. (analyzing convergence of this algorithm is a question in itself).

---

```
function X = unitaryCubeRoot(B,C,maxit)
% Matlab code to solve: X*X*B*X*C=I
  n = size(B,1);
  W = eye(n);
  for k=1:maxit
    W = B*sqrtm(W)'*C;
    X = sqrtm(W)';
    fprintf('%d: %E\n',k, norm(X*X*B*X*C-eye(n)));
  end
end
```

Comment: The equation does not always have a unique solution: for instance, take $n=1$ and $A=B=C=1$, and it becomes $X^3=I$, with three complex unitary solutions.

Comment: Ok, I think under suitable assumptions on $B$ and $C$, perhaps this could be made to have a unique "local" solution (in terms of the matrices being within an "injectivity radius")...

Comment: @FedericoPoloni:  In fact, $X^3=I$ has infinitely many solutions:  For each splitting $\mathbb{C}^3 = \mathbb{C}^2\oplus \mathbb{C}$, you can let $X$ be $\omega$ times the identity on the $\mathbb{C}^2$ and $\omega^2$ times the identity on $\mathbb{C}$ (where $\omega$ is a cube root of unity).  Since there are infinitely many splittings, there are infinitely many solutions.

Comment: @Suvrit:  You asked whether your invocation of the Brouwer fixed point theorem was justified.  The answer is 'no, it is not'.  Not only is $\mathrm{U}(n)$ not contractible, it has many 'holes' in the sense that its real homology groups have a total dimension of $2^n$, so it is very, very far from being a topologically simple space.  There is certainly no well-defined square root operation; the typical element of $\mathrm{U}(n)$ has $2^n$ square roots.

Comment: @RobertBryant: Thanks for clarifying this! I was worried that I am wrongly invoking Brouwer, and indeed I was. Surprisingly, the Matlab iteration that I wrote, succeeds fairly often; maybe Matlab's sqrtm is picking up a "reasonable" square-root.

Comment: @Suvrit: I'm not familiar with Matlab's routines, so I don't know what it is doing.  Anyway, what I should have written is that there is no *continuous* square root operation in $\mathrm{U}(n)$ (and you would need continuous to invoke BFPT anyway).  Of course, there does exist a square root operation, but there can't be a continuous one, even when $n=1$.